# [MoveIt!] Can't plan to a pose goal

Tags: ros, python, moveit, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using a simple 4 DoF arm and want to use MoveIt! to calculate and execute trajectories for it.
I followed the [setup tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html) and the [Move Group Python Interface Tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html) which allow me to give the pr2 a pose goal to which he then plans a trajectory.

However, when I'm using this approach on my own model it doesn't work.
I tried various Cartesian coordinates as pose goal, some that he is definitively able to reach, but I always receive:

```
Fail: ABORTED: No motion plan found. No execution attempted.
```

and

```
RRTConnect: Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree
```

I even (unsuccessfully) tried to move to the current position using:

```
pose_target = group.get_current_pose()
group.set_pose_target(pose_target)
```

The second application from the tutorial of planning to a joint-space goal is working correctly.

The planning group I use contains all 4 joints of the arm nothing else (I also tried a group containing all joints and links).
I also added an end-effector in the setup, but it didn't help.

This problem is annoying me for some time already, every hint or solution is welcomed :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242507/%5Bmoveit!%5D-can%27t-plan-to-a-pose-goal/) by [F4bich](https://answers.ros.org/users/27705/f4bich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2016-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-28**:
Seeing as joint space targets work, but Cartesian ones don't: what kind of IK plugin are you using? KDL? That is known to not work that well with < 6 DoF. See if 'enable position only IK' works for you. Other options: try trac_ik or IKFast.

**Comment by [F4bich](https://answers.ros.org/users/27705/f4bich/) on 2016-08-29**:
I was using KDL. I now tested it with tracik, but it is not working any better.
However, I noticed that occasionally the ik solver does find a path, but only very rarely and without any pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As gvdhoorn pointed out correctly, the IK solver had problems with the < 6 DoF robot. Using trac_ik didn't help, however, adding more DoF did.

---

Originally posted by [F4bich](https://answers.ros.org/users/27705/f4bich/) with karma: 79 on 2016-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-11**:
Planning for 4DOFs should actually be possible, but does require a working IK solver. Have you tried using IKFast, or writing your own?

**Comment by [F4bich](https://answers.ros.org/users/27705/f4bich/) on 2016-10-11**:
Not yet, I used the 4DoF robot only for testing purposes and now moved to a more complex robot.